# How do I pass parameters to an angular service or factory?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This plunker shows it best: http://plnkr.co/edit/y3uacaQSc1MbrWKfb0At?p=preview

but here is the code:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope,testFactory) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
  var test_var = "iceland";
  $scope.testFunction = testFactory.testFunction;

});

app.service('testFactory',function(){

  this.testFunction = function(){
    alert(test_var);
  };

})
```

and in the html:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <p ng-click="testFunction()">Hello {{name}}!</p>

  </body>
```

right now, as you can see in the plunkr, test_var is undefined this makes sense because its not defined... So I want to pass it from the controller, but if I do something like 
`$scope.testFunction = testFactory.testFunction(test_var);`, then the testFunction executes along with the alert because of the parentheses. But I just want to pass test_var, not execute the function. How can I pass it in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap the call in a function so that the call to `testFactory.testFunction(test_var)` is only invoked when `$scope.testFunction()` is...

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope,testFactory) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
  var test_var = "iceland";
  $scope.testFunction = function() {
    testFactory.testFunction(test_var);
  };
});

app.service('testFactory',function(){

  this.testFunction = function(test_var){
    alert(test_var);
  };

})
```